# How to resolve : Unable to load DLL 'OraOps19.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, odp.net

I have installed the oracle 19 client to build my project. In my registry the dll path is well defined [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ5JH.png)

and i've also add `<oracle.dataaccess.client><settings><add name="DllPath" value="D:\app\oracle\product\19.0.0\client_1\bin"/></settings></oracle.dataaccess.client>`

but i still have the exception

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps19.dll': The specified
> procedure could not be found.

How can i see the dll path used or resolve the problem ?

Comment: Did you mix 32-bit and 64-bit? Maybe have a look at https://github.com/Wernfried/connection-tester

Comment: Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which path is searched

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I don't mix 32-bit and 64-bit but with process monitor my application seems to use dll from oracle client 12 and I don't know why. In my personal computer I've oracle 11, 12 & 19

Comment: I don't think it is a smart idea to have more than one Oracle client installed (i.e. one each for 32-bit and 64-bit). I cannot imagine any reason to have it. You would have to change your `PATH` variable accordingly for each program you start. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992

Comment: why would you even use Full oracle client these days? There are better connectivity options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load DLL “OraOps10.dll”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683661/unable-to-load-dll-oraops10-dll)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a wrong path to **oci.dll** in the Windows registry.

I managed to catch that only after writing a small console application and analyzing an application running log created by the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) tool:

Tools - File Summary - ByFolder tree helped to find a record that reads the wrong path value from the Windows registry

I put the following fixes:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\MTxOCI]
"OracleOciLibPath"="C:\\PATH_TO_YOUR_ORACLE_CLIENT\\bin"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSDTC\MTxOCI]
"OracleOciLibPath"="C:\\PATH_TO_YOUR_ORACLE_CLIENT\\bin"
```

It fixed the error.

Comment: is this supposed to be the location of `oci.dll` or `OraOps19.dll` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case what resolved the issue was to install C++ Redistributeable:

```
# ODAC requires the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2022 or later:
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; 
Invoke-WebRequest "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe" -OutFile "vc_redist.x64.exe"; 
Start-Process -filepath .\vc_redist.x64.exe -ArgumentList "/install", "/passive", "/norestart" -Passthru | Wait-Process; 
Remove-Item -Force vc_redist.x64.exe;
```

it's an requirement mentioned at the ODAC downloading page

[image]